# What does this mean in a html form?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, postback

What does this mean in a web form?

I took this code for a button on a webpage. I am not able to understand this. Can someone help me understand this?

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Button8" value="View all details" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Button8&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Button8" style="color:#000066;background-color:#F2F2F2;width:98px;" />
```

Comment: What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: @sword22 i dont understand what goes within the onclick part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input
```

A form control

```
type="submit"
```

That submits a form

```
name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Button8"
```

And has a name so you can see that this control submitted the form on the server

```
value="View all details"
```

And has a value which will be sent to the server and used as text

```
onclick="
```

It has obtrusive JavaScript. This is poor style, [unobtrusive JS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) is preferred.

```
javascript:
```

Someone has joined a cargo cult. They probably think that this means "This script is written in JavaScript", but it actually is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). As there is no loop, it is pointless.

```
WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(
    new WebForm_PostBackOptions(
        &quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Button8&quot;, 
        &quot;&quot;, 
        true, 
        &quot;&quot;, 
        &quot;&quot;, 
        false, 
        false))
```

This calls a function which you haven't provided.

Note that since it is inside an attribute value delimited with `"`, any `"` characters have to be represented with HTML entities (`&quote`). This makes it hard to read, which is one of the drawbacks of using obtrusive JS.

The first argument is the name of the control, which leads me to wonder why it doesn't just use `this`.

```
" 
id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Button8"
```

An id so the input can be referenced from other scripts.

```
style="color:#000066;background-color:#F2F2F2;width:98px;" />
```

Some styling that should be placed in an external stylesheet.

Comment: so is it WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions and WebForm_PostBackOptions are two functions.i don't see them in the page..Does that mean they are some server side functions..?

Comment: No, it means you haven't found where they are defined in the page (or an `src`ed `<script>`).

Comment: I am actually writing a java program to fetch a part of webpage. This is the url of the page http://www.tpcindia.com/track.aspx?id=CGL1234567 After clicking on View all details on this page i get more details on the page.
I want this data to be extracted in my program.What could be done..?

Comment: @imbond Its been a long time. I am not sure if I remember anything.

Comment: @rgksugan I've solved it using selenium. But when the application will be uploaded on production, it will not work. So finding alternative solution. Any help from your end will be appreciated, Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like something asp.net generate, and its an ajax web form.